# How to Profile a Kotlin app in Android Studio

Tags: android, profiler

How do I profile an Android Kotlin app so that I can see which methods take how many time?

(I already tried to follow the official documentation but they write stuff like "The profiler automatically displays its tracing information in the trace pane" which is not true as it does not popup or show anything. Also the Recording Configurations they listed don't even exist ...)

The best thing I got was a view that showed me something like 100% CPU, 50% Memory, ... but no details on a method basis.

Comment: You may want to improve your question with links to existing features which do/don't meet your needs like: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/record-traces and/or identify your version of Android Studio.